# Printing out scraped data with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here is the way I came up with to print out scraped data:

```
pool_to_search_for_loads = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchResults"]/div[5]/div')

loads_contact = pool_to_search_for_loads.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'contact')
loads_origin = pool_to_search_for_loads.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'origin')
loads_dest = pool_to_search_for_loads.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'dest')

def parse_printer(info1, info2, info3):
    count = 0
    while count < len(info1):
        print(info1[count].text, ' from ', info2[count].text, ' to ', info3[count].text)
        count += 1

parse_printer(loads_contact, loads_origin, loads_dest)
```

This gives me such output:

```
(800) 999-0101  from  Hernando, FL  to  Port Huron, MI
(800) 999-0101  from  Albany, GA  to  Dayton, OH
(800) 999-0101  from  Valdosta, GA  to  Cincinnati, OH
(800) 999-0101  from  Tallahassee, FL  to  Indianapolis, IN
(800) 999-0101  from  Macon, GA  to  Lexington, KY
```

Writing a function for such seems to be an overkill, is there a more elegant way to print out results?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you need to retain the loads_contact, loads_origin, and loads_dest variables for other usage. You could use list comprehension to extract the text.

```
loads_contact = [x.text for x in pool_to_search_for_loads.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'contact')]
loads_origin = [x.text for x in pool_to_search_for_loads.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'origin')]
loads_dest = [x.text for x in pool_to_search_for_loads.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'dest')]
```

Then you could zip those 3 into 1 list and then use the items in that 1 list (combined with f-string).

```
for item in zip(loads_contact, loads_origin, loads_dest):
    print(f"{item[0]} from {item[1]} to {item[2]}")
```

Comment: this is a clever way! thank you for your answer! 
i just tried it on my code and it worked, then i tried to expand your way onto the rest of data (same 'loads_something') and for some magical reason code ran smoothly, no error, but no data was printed out haha
by the way, your way is indeed more elegant, but x2 more time consuming